# Eclipse keeps information about breakpoints in exported jar?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, remote-debugging, jpda

I was following this article about [Remote debugging with Eclipse](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/index.html) and I was surprised by:

```
Debug an application remotely (sub title)
...
2. Set a breakpoint
...
4. Export the Java project
5. Run the Java application manually
6. Debug the application remotely
```

This in fact means that breakpoint information is saved inside the exported jar file.

Is it really true? **How can one disable it when exporting a jar?**

**What is the mechanism, is it saved inside .class, in byte code?**

Then I have created remote debug configuration without specifying the project and started debug. The execution of exported jar was really breakpointed in a right place according to stack trace.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Eclipse doesn't export breakpoints to jar files. It keeps them in its own workspace such as when the running application hits the code that has a breakpoint set, it just acts accordingly.

Comment: You are right, this time I close the project with source code and jar execution does not stop. Eclipse is too clever if without specify `Project` in image about it can match.